# How do I change the order of integration $\int_{\pi/2}^{5\pi/2} \int_{\sin x}^{1} f(x,y)dydx$

Tags: multiple-integral

How do I change the order of integration in $$\int_{\pi/2}^{5\pi/2} \int_{\sin x}^{1} f(x,y)dydx\;?$$

$y=\sin x$; $y=1$, $x=\pi/2$; $x= 5\pi/2$.

I can guess from here that $y$ is from $-1$ to $1$.

Then $x=\sin^{-1}(y)$ and $\sin^{-1}(-1) = -\pi/2$ and $\sin^{-1}(1)=\pi/2$.

What will be the limits of $x$?

Comment: You're going to mess up if you try to deal with inverse trig like that. Draw a picture of the region being integrated over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't fit in a comment (so please don't downvote), nevertheless this may help to see the limits in both $x$ and $y$, and thus allow anyone to rearrange the order of integration.  Note, for instance, that the first integration can be over $-1 \leq y \leq 1$.  Then you set the limits on $x$ as a function of $y$.

[image: Region to be integrated]

Comment: This doesn't help. Could you elaborate it please.

Comment: See revised posting.

Comment: However that is where I am stuck- finding limit of $x$, $x=sin^{-1}(y)$ but then what else do I have to do.?

Comment: Find both the lower *and* the upper limits on $x$ (as a function of $y$), and you're done!

Comment: So it will be like $x=sin^{-1}(y)+\pi$ and lower limit of $y$ will be $-1$ so we get $-\pi/2$ and we are adding a $\pi$ to make it $\pi/2$. Similarly the upper limit?

Comment: That's it... just be careful with $\sin$ vs. $\cos$, $\pm \pi$, and such... but you have the right idea now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the equation of the form $x=a+b \cdot \text{sin}^{-1}(y)$ passing through $\left( \frac{3\pi}{2},-1\right)$ and $\left( \frac{\pi}{2},1\right).$ So $\frac{3\pi}{2}=a + b \cdot \text{sin}^{-1}(-1)$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}=a + b \cdot  \text{sin}^{-1}(1)$. Now you have a system of 2 linear equations in $a$ and $b$. Solve for $a$ and $b$.
$$ $$
Also find the equation of the form $x=a+b \cdot \text{sin}^{-1}(y)$ passing through $\left( \frac{3\pi}{2},-1\right)$ and $\left( \frac{5\pi}{2},1\right).$